# Irish Red Recipe

Tags: beer, recipe

My friend and I are brewing 3 batches of beer for St. Patrick's Day this year. We are going to make a green pale ale, a milk stout, and we want to make an Irish Red. The unfortunate part is the only recipe I can find that I like is a clone-brew of MacQueen’s Nessie Original Red Ale.

Does anyone have/know where to find a good recipe?

Comment: Stumbled upon BrewToad.com this site is amazing.

Comment: http://meta.homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11/recipe-questions    We can help you change the flavor profile of a recipe that you've already got, but we can't help you come up with recipes.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the bevy of recipe databases out there:

- [hopville](http://hopville.com/recipes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=red)
- [beertools](http://www.beertools.com/library/search.php?style=72&category=none&grain=none&extract=none&adjunct=none&hop=none&text=&sort=recent&order=d)
- [brewersfriend](http://www.brewersfriend.com/homebrew/beer/)
- [tastybrew](http://www.tastybrew.com/newrcp/styleview.html)
- [BrewToad](http://www.brewtoad.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=red%20ale)
- [HBT](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f12/)

Most online homebrew supply shops offer pdf downloads of their recipes.  Really like NB's Irish Red? Grab the recipe, and give it a try.

Honestly, there are so many recipes out there I find it hard to separate the wheat from the chaff so to speak.  Google is your friend.